# CSS: Rows-columns borders are not showing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I just started getting into web-app development and I have a question about css/boostrap.

This is my template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    display
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="font-size:150%">
            <div class="col-md-2">Symbol</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">Name</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">Shares</div> 
            <div class="col-md-2">Price</div> 
            <div class="col-md-2">Sum</div>
     </div> 
    {% for elem in p %}
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ elem.stock }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ elem.name }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">{{ elem.shares }}</div> 
            <div class="col-md-2">${{ elem.price }}</div> 
            <div class="col-md-2">${{ elem.total}}</div>
     </div>   
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"> TOTAL SPENDED:</div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-6">${{overall_total}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">CASH LEFT:</div>          
        <div class="col-md-offset-6">${{cash_left}}</div>
    </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm using Flask and passing different values to a table. The problem is that when creating my table, it doesn't have any borders or colors. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks guys.

Here's a picture of it:

[image]

Comment: You should look into <table> tag which is there for tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no css which would actually give borders to your rows, I would suggest to add this code inside your div container, before any row

```
<style>
  .row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a bootstrap styled table would be the better choice. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Answer (score 1):

By default bootstrap has no border adding to the row. There are two ways

1. add border directly to the row

`.row {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}`

2. using pseudo class if you want more control on the border

```
.row {
   position: relative;
}



.row:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1px;
   background: black;
   left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better give a background color to you main div and give a padding of 1px for the cells and background color white.

```
.container-fluid{
   background-color : black ;
}
.container-fluid .col-md-2 {
   padding: 1px;
   background-color: white;
}
```